# How does an LLVM backend handle getelementptr for structs with dynamic access?

Tags: struct, llvm

How does a backend for LLVM handle code like this

```
%t2 = getelementptr %struct.ST, %struct.ST* %s, i32 %t1
```

where the type is a struct and the index is not a constant.

---

I understand that `getelementptr` is basically computing the offset of the element we want from the base of the data structure that contains it. So in common cases, I understand how it would be compiled in the back end. For example:

```
%t4 = getelementptr [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %t3, i32 %t2
```

You basically compute `%t3 + %t2 * 32` (where 32 is the size of `i32`). Similarly, for structs

```
%struct.ST = type { i32, double, %struct.RT }
%t1 = getelementptr %struct.ST, %struct.ST* %s, i32 2
```

Should return a pointer to the `double` in the struct, so , you just compute `%s + 32` (where 32 is the size of the first element of type `i32`).

---

The two cases I spelled out seem to be the most common cases when compiling from C code. In C you access struct elements by 'name'. However LLVM allow accessing structs by 'index', so the following is valid:

```
%struct.ST = type { i32, double, %struct.RT }
%t2 = getelementptr %struct.ST, %struct.ST* %s, i32 t1
```

How do backends handle this case? Is it disallowed in some cases? Do they loop over the structure? Do they write a lookup table in memory? (All of the options I can think of seem wasteful)

Comment: GEP generally accepts only constant arguments, except in arrays, so the problem does not arise.

Comment: That's what I expect it, but I couldn't find anything about it in the language reference. Do you have any source for that?

Comment: It's in the language reference.